# PHP SimpleTest / xdebug code coverage test - ignore some lines

Tags: php, code-coverage, xdebug, simpletest

I have a problem with SimpleTest / xdebug test classes - specifically, I have registered a shutdown function to close my test coverage and save the results.

However, this still (correctly) shows up as never reached:

```
if (error_condition) {
    die();
} // This line is never actually reached, and shows up in the report as unreached, confusing the automatic analyzers.
```

Short of avoiding using 'die' for exits, and using exceptions instead, is there a way to mark a line up as 'do not test' ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SimpleTest has this, but, it should not even consider it as "not covered". It's just unreachable, and that is not a problem.

Comment: Considering it as 'not covered' would be preferred. For some silly reason it's still considered reachable, just not covered..

Comment: That's odd. Can I get a whole file example in the question?